# Rails partial locals in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way in RoR to access current partial locals in helper. I want something like

```
<% render partial: 'foo', locals: { :foo: 'bar' } %>
```

then to be accessed in lets say ApplicationHelper:

```
def my_helper_method
  ...
  my_var = ...local_assigns[:foo] # should assign 'bar'
  ...
end
```

Other way to describe the problem would be: How do I pass all the locals passed to a partial to my helper method implicitly? If I do it explicitly, there are a lot of boilerplate code, which just pass partial arguments to to a helper method, and I have so many of them.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Would you like to describe your question a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helpers have no knowledge of local variables inside partials. Unless you explicitly pass them a  parameter, you can't do what you are proposing. What you can do is take an object-oriented approach using [presenters](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch), and avoid using helpers all together.

Either make your own, as outlined in the Railscasts episodes, or use a gem like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper). Personally, I am in favour of the "roll your own" approach because it's very simple.

Some pseudo-code to get the idea across:

```
class FooPresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object, @template = object, template
  end

  def amazing_foo
    @template.content_tag :div, class: 'foo' do
      "#{@object.name}: Wow! this is incredible!"
    end
  end
end

module FooHelper
  def present_foo(object)
    presenter = FooPresenter.new(object, self)
    yield presenter if block_given?
    presenter
  end
end
```

Just instantiate that from your view.

```
= present_foo(foo) do
  = amazing_foo
```

Yay, no need to pass params.

Helpers are just modules floating around in the namespace, and frankly, much of the time they encourage bad coding practices. Presenters offer a clear OOP way of handling complex view logic. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would pass the parameter into the method from the view, so change your method to be:

```
def my_helper_method(input_param)
  ...
  my_var = ...foo # should assign 'bar'
  ...
end
```

and call this as any other method in the view passing foo as the input_param.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send param to my_helper_method

```
def my_helper_method(foo)
  ...
  my_var = foo
  ...
end
```

in partial

```
<%= my_helper_method(foo) %>
```

Comment: the question is how to avoid this, as there are a lot of locals used, and typing it all every time in every partial is giving me a LOT of boilerplate code.